# RCS Version Control on Tramp Mode

Tags: tramp, version-control

Began using `RCS` Version Control within Emacs with no problem while locally, but having dificulty on Tramp mode, once it says:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "This file is already registered")
  signal(error ("This file is already registered"))
  error("This file is already registered")
  vc-register((RCS ("/scp:user@192.168.1.3#2222:/home/user/Teste/Teste01.txt") ("/scp:user@192.168.1.3#2222:/home/user/Teste/Teste01.txt") unregistered locking))
  vc-next-action(nil)
  funcall-interactively(vc-next-action nil)
  call-interactively(vc-next-action nil nil)
  command-execute(vc-next-action)
```

Created file, stroke `C-v-v`, set `RCS` as backend, made some changes, saved it, when stroke `C-v-v` to insert changes, received upward error massage.

Already certified that both directory and files were on `Tramp` user login.

Anyway that `RCS` could be used within `Tramp` mode?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an error in the `vc-rcs` backend. I've tried to register a remote file in RCS, like you did. My debug trace looks different:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Failed (status 1): ci  -u -t- /ssh:gandalf:/tmp/aa...")
  signal(error ("Failed (status 1): ci  -u -t- /ssh:gandalf:/tmp/aa..."))
  error("Failed (%s): %s" "status 1" "ci  -u -t- /ssh:gandalf:/tmp/aaa/aaa")
  vc-do-command("*vc*" 0 "ci" "/ssh:gandalf:/tmp/aaa/aaa" nil "-u" "-t-")
  apply(vc-do-command "*vc*" 0 "ci" "/ssh:gandalf:/tmp/aaa/aaa" nil "-u" "-t-" nil)
  vc-rcs-register(("/ssh:gandalf:/tmp/aaa/aaa") nil)
  apply(vc-rcs-register (("/ssh:gandalf:/tmp/aaa/aaa") nil))
  vc-call-backend(RCS register ("/ssh:gandalf:/tmp/aaa/aaa") nil)
  vc-register((RCS ("/ssh:gandalf:/tmp/aaa/aaa") unregistered locking))
  (progn (vc-register '(RCS ("/ssh:gandalf:/tmp/aaa/aaa") unregistered locking)))
  eval((progn (vc-register '(RCS ("/ssh:gandalf:/tmp/aaa/aaa") unregistered locking))) t)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

However, the `vc-do-command` uses `"/ssh:gandalf:/tmp/aaa/aaa"` as file name, which is wrong. It should use only the local part of that file name, `"/tmp/aaa/aaa"`.

I recommend that you write an Emacs bug report.